# Loop Cuts not working on previously hidden faces

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, edit-mode, loop

Sometimes when using the Loop Cut tool (on something like a cylinder made of quads) I'll hide some faces because I don't want the cut to apear on all of them. When I make the cut and then un-hide the hidden faces and then try to add a new loop cut that includes those faces that were previously hidden, no Loop Cuts show up on those faces anymore.

Is this supposed to happen, should I be letting the loop cut cover all the faces and then just disolve the edges I don't want later.

Comment: I think you answered your own question. If you hide a face, but make a loop cut around the surrounding faces, the cut will terminate at the edge of the face you've "hidden" When you un-hide it again, that face (assuming it was a quad to start), is now an n-gon due to the vertices added by the loop cut when the face was hidden. As you said, either allow the cut to go all the way around and dissolve later, or use edge flow to "section off" the area you want to loop cut, so that way it only cuts across that section, and not your whole model.

Comment: Oooo ok of course, thank you. Also what is edge flow, if you don't mind explaining.

Comment: Edge flow is a term for controlling the direction of face loops and whatnot. It's a topology "technique" that is really good to learn the practice of early on. It basically involves the use of "poles" (a vertex with more than 4 edges extending from it) to change the direction of where blender counts a "closed loop". See the guide below: edge flow is #3 about halfway down the page - https://cgcookie.com/articles/guide-to-clean-topology

Comment: Thank you very much